# Detecting selected text with powershell

Tags: powershell

Is it possible to detect selected text with powershell?

For instance, say I opened a text file that contained an essay and then sent a command to select the first line.

Is there a way to return the first line of that file as a string?

Comment: How are you "opening" the file? In powershell or in an editor? If powershell then you can `Get-Content` cmdlet to get the first line of a file.

Comment: "and then sent a command to select the first line" - how? From PowerShell? What if multiple instances of `notepad.exe` is open? How will you choose the "right" one?

Comment: Let's say there is no file and you're just wanting to Ctrl-C the highlighted text on the screen. This does not seem to put that selected text onto the clipboard

    [System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait('^{c}')

But this doesn't seem to put the text onto the clipboard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to iterate over the lines of a text file you can access them like this:

```
$file = Get-Content essay.txt
$file[0]  # for first line
$file[$file.Length - 1] # for last line
```

Comment: This is roundabout what I was looking for, thank you!